# Achieving a double join in sql

Tags: java, sql, join

I have three tables: `Books`, `Members` and `loanRecords`.

The `Books` table has `bookname,bookid, etc..`

The `Members` table has `memberid,membername etc..`

The `Loan` records hold who has loaned what as in: `bookid,memberid,loandate etc...`

What I am trying to do is write a join which can list all the member with a specific book title out on loan and i may be getting a little confused.
I know i have to

```
SELECT * from member"+
"JOIN member_loans_book on member_loans_book.Member_id=member.id "
+ " AND member_loans_book.Book_id=...
```

but when i get this far i get flabbergasted.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing pretty good. This select might be something what you're looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM member m
    JOIN member_loans_book mlb ON m.id = mlb.member_id
    JOIN book b ON b.id = mlb.book_id
    WHERE b.title = 'MyBook';
```

Comment: Thats the quickest solution i have ever gotten from this site; hehe Thanks for the help Tomasz. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on sql in java, but I can create the query you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM Member m
JOIN Loans l ON l.memberid=m.memberid
JOIN Books b ON l.bookid=b.bookid
WHERE b.title = 'BookTitle'
```